# Ember Data 2.0 model won't get records

Tags: ember.js

I can't seem to get Ember Data to work with my API format. Right now my API is like so:

```
{
  data: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Some Company",
      primary_contact: "Bob Smith"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Another Company",
      primary_contact: "Bob Smith"
    },
  ]
}
```

I know that Ember wants the key to be **organizations** rather then **data** but that is just not possible. I've been trying to get it working with a serializer, and I don't know if I'm even on the right track. Here is what I currently have.

```
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  normalizeResponse: function(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
  var pluralTypeKey = Ember.String.pluralize(requestType.typeKey);
  payload[pluralTypeKey] = payload['data'];
  delete payload['data'];

  return this._super(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType);
}
```

Any help would be **GREATLY** appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `primaryModelClass.modelName` instead `requestType`.

`requestType` is just string like 'findAll', 'findRecord' and etc.

```
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  normalizeResponse: function(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
    var pluralTypeKey = Ember.String.pluralize(primaryModelClass.modelName);
    payload[pluralTypeKey] = payload['data'];
    delete payload['data'];
    return this._super(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType);
}
```

Working jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/weyuwixoli/edit?js,output

Comment: Thank you so much, that was it!